# need DDL for all the tables under schemas in Redshift in one go

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I need to create another redshift cluster in different region from my existing redshift cluster.so, i need the DDL for the all the tables of all schemas of my existing Redshift cluseter.please assist.

Please note - i tried runnng the script mentioned in the link to create views but it's not working - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd migrate a snapshot of the database to the other region and restore a new cluster from this snapshot.  AWS has a page on doing exactly this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/migrate-your-amazon-redshift-cluster-to-another-aws-region/

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the suggestion.on the same thread if you could tell me what is the way/script to get DDL for all the tables for RDS MYSQL databases.